# Exception supposedly never thrown even though it does at runtime

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to write a small program where I came to the following problem:

In one of my methods I have the following piece of code

```
try{
    rootHuman = Human.load(scanner.next());
}catch(FileNotFoundException f){
    //Missing Code              
}
```

where I try to catch a FileNotFoundException. So looking at the function call from Human.load() we have this piece of code

```
public static Human load(String filename){
    try{
        Human human;
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(filename);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        human = (Human) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
        return human;
    }catch(IOException i){
        i.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException c){
        c.printStackTrace();
        return null;
}
```

also when trying to catch the FileNotFoundException here I get the same problem. My Problem is that the compiler tells me that this exception is never thrown, but when I execute the code I can obviously get a  FileNotFoundException when the input from scanner.next() is a filename that doesn't exist. I'm kind of pointless here so any piece of advice is very much welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Human#load` is not declared to throw a `FileNotFoundException`. Inside `load`, you swallow the exception and return `null`. It's already "handled".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your compiler complains about this:

```
try{
    rootHuman = Human.load(scanner.next());
}catch(FileNotFoundException f){
    //Missing Code              
}
```

In your `Human.load` method you catch a `IOException`, so a `FileNotFoundException` (witch is actually a sub-type of IOException) will never be thrown in method "load", this catch clausule will always handle it.

Remove the try catch block when calling `Human.load()`:

```
 rootHuman = Human.load(scanner.next());
```

Comment: Right it's very obvious now!! So is there any possibility to move the catch block from the load method to the other location? I'm only considering this because of style reasons so I wouldn't mind much if not.

Comment: you can do it, just remove the catch clausule  `catch(IOException i)` and rename the method to:
`public static Human load(String filename) throws IOException`
But, if you have a method that load a file from the file system y recomend you to catch the exception as soon as you can, and return null when there is a problem, as you were doing.

Comment: Ok thanks a bunch you really helped me out there! (not too used to java yet)